# Rails: Routing to a different controller based on request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I'm writing an app where I want all requests for HTML to be handled by the same controller action. I have some other routes that are JSON-specific. Here's what my routes look like:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints format: :json do
    resources :posts
  end

  match "(*path)" => "web#index"
end
```

The problem is that `constraints` is being interpreted as "this route only works with the specified format" rather than "skip this route and try the next one if the request is not in the specified format."

In other words, navigating to */posts* in the browser gives me a *406 Not Acceptable* because the URL is constrained to the JSON format. Instead, I want it to fall through to *web#index* if the request is for HTML, and hit the resourceful route if the request is for JSON. How can this be achieved?

(Using Rails 3.2.9.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've thought about this, and come to some conclusions.

- You might not want all routes to return the single page app HTML, because there are some paths that you'll ideally want to return an HTTP 404 status code from.
- Your HTTP routes will be different from your JSON routes
- You definitely should be routing different formats to different controllers
- It might be advantageous to define all your HTML routes in your Rails router, so that you can use it to generate a javascript router. There is at least one gem that does this
- Rails does not have this functionality and this gem https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter doesn't really seem like the right tool. Here is my attempt: [Rails routing-filter route all html requests to one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261154/rails-routing-filter-route-all-html-requests-to-one-action)
- Having to namespace your JSON API under a module Api to avoid routing collisions is no bad thing.
- Don't have content visible to Google on your single page app, or you'll get banned for duplicate content.

I took a slightly different approach, which doesn't really answer the question, but I think it has a few advantages:

Here is my config/routes.rb

```
FooApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # Route all resources to your frontend controller. If you put this
  # in a namespace, it will expect to find another frontend controller
  # defined in that namespace, particularly useful if, for instance,
  # that namespace is called Admin and you want a separate single page
  # app for an admin interface. Also, you set a convention on the names
  # of your HTML controllers. Use Rails's action_missing method to
  # delegate all possible actions on your frontend controllers.

  def html_resources(name, options, &block)
    resources(name, options.merge(:controller => "frontend"), &block)
  end

  # JSON API
  namespace :api do
    resources :things, :except => [:edit, :new]
  end

  # HTML
  html_resources :things, :only => [:edit, :new, :index, :show] do
    get :other_action
  end
end


class FrontendController < ApplicationController
  def action_missing(*args, &block)
    render :index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think different controllers for the same action is not the "Rails way".
Probably you can solve your problem with low level custom request handler in the middleware.

Comment: not really.. in case of a single page application this might be exactly what you want to have. Html requests just produce a simple layout filled on the client side. Json requests produce route specific  json output.

Comment: I heard that some of the top Rails people at Google had done this kind of controller separation, and it's perfect for use in a single page app. Having thin controllers is most definitely the rails way, and so is the DRYness and simplicity of routing several URLs to the same page from config/routes.rb rather than configuring the behaviour in each controller method. In general, having one extra controller for a distinct concern is better than coupling every controller to that concern. Sorry for flaming and I'll try to think of a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format in your constraints, e.g.

```
match '*path', constraints: { path: /foo.*/, format: 'html'}, to: 'home#index', via: [:get]
```